# creating a Tinder Bot, but i have an attributeError problem 'driver'

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to create a Tinder bot from a video that i have seen online but i am getting 'AttributeError: 'TinderBot' object has no attribute 'driver'

can you please help me on how to solve this problem

```
from selenium import webdriver
class TinderBot():
def _init_(self):
    self. driver=webdriver.chrome()
```

[image]

if i use the `def __init__(self):` instead of `def _init_(self):` it gives me an error
[image]

Comment: It's `__init__`, not `_init_`.

Comment: it is giving me an error how to remove it

Comment: As @elias26 said, it's `webdriver.Chrome()` with capital `C`.

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a few syntax errors, try this:

```
class TinderBot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver=webdriver.Chrome()
```

Comment: please check my edits the error it is giving me thanks .